# Upload picture with ajax in django application

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm stuck with a problem in a django application. I have an ajax function to upload a single image to a model but, so far, I wasn't able to succeed in my goal.
What I basically achieve is that I get the file from Ajax but, when I try to send it on my Django request in the view, the result is None object.
Let me post some code to be more clear:

HTML:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
     <td>{{question.id}}</td>
     <td>{{question}}</td>
     <td>
      <a title="{% trans "Edit Question" %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'administration:edit_question' pk=question.id %}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
      <a title="{% trans "See Details" %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-3" href="{% url 'administration:question_details' pk=question.id %}" ><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
      <a title="{% trans "Delete Question" %}" href="{% url 'administration:delete_question' pk=question.id %}" id="delete_question" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ms-3"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
      <button title="{% trans "Add Image" %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success ms-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addImageModal{{question.id}}"><i class="fas fa-file-image"></i></button>
      {% if question.explanation %}
      <a title="{% trans "Edit Explanation" %}" href="{% url 'administration:edit_explanation' pk=question.explanation.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info ms-3"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
      <button title="{% trans "Add Explanation Image" %}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addExplanationImageModal{{question.id}}" data-questionId="{{question.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary explanationModals ms-3"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
      {% else %}
       <a title="{% trans "Add Explanation" %}" href="{% url 'administration:add_explanation' pk=question.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info ms-3"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
       {% endif %}
      </td>
 {% include 'administration/modals/add_question_image_modal.html' %}
 {% include 'administration/modals/add_explanation_image_modal.html' %}
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

MODAL:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addExplanationImageModal{{question.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addExplanationImageModalLabel" aria-modal="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">{% trans "Add Explanation Image to Explanation n°" %} {{question.explanation.id}}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" id="explanationImageForm{{question.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>{% trans "Image" %}</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="explanationPicFile{{question.id}}">
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="addExplanationImage{{question.id}}" class="btn btn-success mt-3"> {% trans "Add Image" %} </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3" data-bs-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Close" %}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let explanationModals = [...document.getElementsByClassName('explanationModals')];
explanationModals.forEach((explanationModal) =>
explanationModal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  var questionId = explanationModal.getAttribute("data-questionId");
  
    $('#addExplanationImage'+questionId).on('click', function(e){
        var file = document.getElementById('explanationPicFile'+questionId).files[0]
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/administration/add_ajax_question_explanation_image/' +questionId,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: data,
            cache: false, 
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res)
                console.log(data.get('file'))
            }, 
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err)
            },
        })
    })
})
```

);

views.py

```
def add_ajax_question_explanation_image(request, pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    explanation = Explanation.objects.get(question=question)
    if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        file = request.FILES.get('file')
        image = ExplanationImage(image=file, explanation=explanation)
        image.save()
        return HttpResponse(image)
```

The view is returning correctly but the file is NOT passed inside the image object. If I print the file it returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function so you can able to sent the submitting form.In your code, you are not submitting the code. for that, you need to change the form bellow

```
<form action="/administration/add_ajax_question_explanation_image/{{question.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ajax">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{% trans "Image" %}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" id="explanationPicFile{{question.id}}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success mt-3"> {% trans "Add Image" %} </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3" data-bs-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Close" %}</button>
</form>
```

above I added URL, changed the button type to 'submit' and added class ajax. now when submitting the form we can send data using the ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.ajax', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $this.attr('action');
        data = new FormData(this)
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // your code here
            }
        })
    });
```